# CodeIgniter PHP: use and update variable in controller?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to use a variable in my application with CodeIgniter.

How can I update the value of $my_value inside my controller class example?
My application:

- run test_A() -> run printValue() and result is 10;
- run test_B() -> run printValue() and result is 10;

Why? And how to

- run test_A() -> run printValue() and result is 20;
- run test_B() -> run printValue() and result is 30;

My code:

```
<?php

class example extends CI_Controller
{

    private $my_value;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->my_value = 10;
    }

    public function index()
    {

    }

    public function test_A()
    {
        $this->my_value = 20;
    }

    public function test_B()
    {
        $this->my_value = 30;
    }

    public function printValue()
    {
        echo $this->my_value;
    }

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: just call the function you want before print `my_value`'s value.

Comment: @Badiparmagi, it only prints 10 not 20 or 30. And I want to use updated value for other functions.

Comment: Are you trying to method chain? Otherwise just follow ^ approach.

Comment: If I call new function as function test_C(){ test_A(); printValue();}, it still prints 10.

Comment: @strictlad You can't directly call each method and expecting `$this->my_value` to be changed after each other, but you could pass the returned `$this->my_value` value from one method to be used in other method so the new method will using the passed `$this->my_value` data

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
    private $my_value;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->my_value = 10;
    }

    public function index()
    {

    }

    public function test_A($alter = false)
    {
        $this->my_value = 20;

        if($alter){
            //Alter $this->my_value
        }
    }

    public function test_B($alter = false)
    {
        $this->my_value = 30;

        if($alter){
          //Alter $this->my_value
        }
    }

    public function printValue()
    {
        echo $this->my_value;
    }
```

Then call the function as is if you dont want to alter `$this->my_value` or else call

```
$this->test_A(true);
```

to alter `$this->my_value`

Comment: I want  to use updated value for other functions. I want to change value of $this->my_value and uses it for other function. So $alter is not helpful.

Comment: $this->my_value is accessible in all function on your class, the altered value of it in a function will be it's new value, regardless of where function  it is as long as it is on the same class.

Comment: But $this->my_value did not update it only displays 10 in any case.

Comment: when you change value of $this->my_value in a function, it will become its new value. so when you access the variable on the other function, you will get it's changed value, not its original.

Comment: I also think as you. But my code only print 10. @kamote ulalo

Comment: well i just realize if you call the function thru the browser since youre using codeigniter. what we think won't happen. you should better to use session to retain the value you want .

Answer (score 0):

It's working perfectly on my environment, check this code.

```
class test extends CI_Controller
{

    private $my_value;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->my_value = 10;
    }

    public function index()
    {

    }

    public function test_A()
    {
        $this->my_value = 20;
    }

    public function test_B()
    {
        $this->my_value = 30;
    }

    public function test_C() {
        $this->test_A();
        $this->printValue();
    }
    public function printValue()
    {
        echo $this->my_value;
    }

}
```

Comment: If I remove $this->my_value = 10; from constructor(), my_value is always null.

Comment: check current code, and let me know the output when you run test_C.

Comment: run test_C result is 20. But I need run printValue() after run test_A(), test_B(),... I want test_C() can receive update value without run test_A() inside.

Comment: it's not clear what are you trying to achieve, but if you want value to be hold even after refreshing page then you need to use `session`